# Change color in a object without harming the texture

Tags: c#, image-processing, colors, computer-vision, image-segmentation

My goal is to change the color of an object without damaging the texture. As I understand more like change hue and saturation  or changing the RGB color channels values. By doing threshold I can isolate the object, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to apply the color changes to the object.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found that a way to nicely steer the "general color" of an object to another tint without damaging internal details is to act on the color curves.

[image]

If for example you apply a curve to the green channel by lowering midtones you are basically subtracting greens, thus steering the tint to magenta (red + blue). Using a smooth curve that starts at 0 and ends at 1 however you are not going to change for example the white highlight that will remain white and internal texture will still maintain some of the original tint.